# Exponentially distributed inter-arrival rate

Tags: poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution, queueing-theory

Could someone clarify this question?

> Assume that inter-arrival times of student arriving at the canteen are exponentially distributed with a mean of $\dfrac13$.
>
> a) Find the probability that no students arrive during a $20$ minutes
>   interval.
>
> b) Find the probability that more than two students arrive during the
>   server's ten-minute break.

For part (a), how would I find the the probability of $x=0$ students when exponential distribution only works for $x$ less or equal to a number? Do I need to use Poisson?

For part (b) how would I go about using the break time? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Exponential inter-arrival times is equivalent to Poisson arrivals.  As to your second question, it's just a 10-minute interval like any other.

Comment: @saulspatz why is equivalent to Poisson arrivals? does that mean I plug in 0 in Poisson equation? probability is 0.7165?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183760/what-is-the-correct-inter-arrival-time-distribution-in-a-poisson-process