# What rule is used in this derivation of the interarrival time for the Poisson process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I'm working on calculating the probability distribution of the interarrival time of the Poisson process. The method used in my textbook is very strange I don't understand how the probabilities are calculated. I am familiar with the method used eg. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183760/what-is-the-correct-inter-arrival-time-distribution-in-a-poisson-process) but not the working below. $ N(t) $ is the Poisson process:
$$ P\{N(s) = 1, N(t) = 2\} = P\{\xi_1 \leq s < \xi_2 \leq t < \xi_3\} $$

$$ = P\{\eta_1 \leq s < \eta_1 + \eta_2 \leq t < \eta_1 + \eta_2 + \eta_3\}$$

At this point we have converted the Poisson process into 3 independent, exponentially distributed random variables. But now we have the first conversion of the probability to integrals and I don't understand how it was done:

$$ = \int_{0}^{s} P\{s < u + \eta_2 \leq t < u + \eta_2 + \eta_3\} \lambda e^{-\lambda u} \, du$$

What rule of probability was used? The first inequality has now become the integral and the random variable $ \eta_1 $ has become u in the probability. Is this a well known rule of probablity (and what is it called if so?) or is this somehow a specific property of this problem? And likewise for the next two steps:
$$ = \int_{0}^{s} \left( \int_{s-u}^{t-u} P\{t < u + v + \eta_3\} \lambda e^{-\lambda v} \, dv \right) \lambda e^{-\lambda u} \, du$$

$$ = \int_{0}^{s} \left( \int_{s-u}^{t-u} e^{-\lambda(t-u-v)} \lambda e^{-\lambda v} \, dv \right) \lambda e^{-\lambda u} \, du$$

$$ = \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda s} (t - s). $$

I've been trying to understand this for a few days now and haven't managed to make any progress.

Comment: $s < u + \eta_2 \leq t < u + \eta_2 + \eta_3$ is equivalent to $s-u<\eta_2\leq t-u$ and $t<u+\eta_2+\eta_3$. Just call $v=\eta_2$ (similar for $\eta_1$)

Comment: That makes sense, but how does the $\eta_1$ bound become the first integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more I've found that the rule used in this example is the law of total probability:
$$ P\{A\}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P\{A|X=x\}f_X(x) dx $$
First, we notice that the event can be written as:
$$ \{\eta_1 \leq s < \eta_1 + \eta_2 \leq t < \eta_1 + \eta_2 + \eta_3\} = \{\eta_1 \leq s\} \cap \{ s < \eta_1 + \eta_2 \leq t < \eta_1 + \eta_2 + \eta_3\} $$
Since $\eta_1$ is exponentially distribution it is non-negative, and the event $\{\eta_1 \leq s\}$ has 0 probability for $\eta_1 > s$ which we can use to adjust the bounds of the integral, therefore we find that:
$$= P\{\eta_1 \leq s < \eta_1 + \eta_2 \leq t < \eta_1 + \eta_2 + \eta_3\}$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(\{\eta_1 \leq s < \eta_1 + \eta_2 \leq t < \eta_1 + \eta_2 + \eta_3\}|\eta_1=u)f_{\eta_1}(u) du$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(\{u \leq s < u + \eta_2 \leq t < u + \eta_2 + \eta_3\})f_{\eta_1}(u) du$$
$$=\int_{0}^{s} P(\{s < u + \eta_2 \leq t < u + \eta_2 + \eta_3\})\lambda e^{-\lambda u} \,  du$$

The rule is applied again to the next two equalities in this way as well.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that for a continuous random variable $X$ with probability distribution function $f_X(x)$, the cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$ is given by $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(\chi) d\chi$.

In the given expression, we have applied that definition to the random variable $\eta_1$ along with the usual decomposition for independent events $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$.

Comment: If I assume the events are independent and do that I get $ \int_{0}^{s}  \lambda e^{-\lambda u} \, du P\{s < u + \eta_2 \leq t < u + \eta_2 + \eta_3\}$, with the second probability outside of the integral. I'm also not sure if the events $ \{s < u + \eta_2 \leq t < u + \eta_2 + \eta_3\} $ and  $ \{ u  \leq s\} $ are independent.